# onClose() doesn't execute when turning Connection off

Tags: android, websocket, autobahn

I'm facing the following issue:
I'm using the de.tavendo.autobahn lib to handle WS connections.
I run my app on a Samsung Galaxy s4 mini device, when I run my app, I connect to my WS server and after that I turn the WiFi off I expect receiving a CLOSE_INTERNAL_ERROR code in the onClose() callback. But the event doesn't seem to be fired on debug.

I tried it on an Acer Iconia tablet and it worked well. Is that a specific issue concerning Samsung devices?

Regards.

Comment: ... Autobahn? Are you too a fan of Kraftwerk?

Comment: Autobahn == fast (WebSocket): http://autobahn.ws/ ;)

Comment: You might try sending stuff e.g. every 1 sec and see what happens if you turn off Wifi.

Comment: Hi again oberset, I did what you suggested and when I take a look at my logs, it seems that the WebSocketConnection object never reach the disconnected state when I switch to airplane mode and my thread keeps on sending messages each second without getting any response.

Comment: More precisely, WebSocketConnection.isConnected() still returns true and WebSocketConnection.sendTextMessage is still working.

Comment: Having the same issue on some devices with OkHttp. The only workaround I found so far is listening to the device's network state and then closing WS manually when device is off network.